# Excel - if value exists in a range then

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need a formula that will:
Refer to a specific cell E1, check if E1 has any value at B column in table "Table1".
In table "Table1", at B column, there are different values (including duplicated values) corresponding to cell E1. If a specific text "Mary" is available, then return "Mary"; otherwise, return the first data corresponding to that cell.

Example:

[image]

Expected results:

F1: Mary
F2: John

Comment: (1) You say you’re checking cell `E1` against Column `B`, but it looks like you’re checking it against Column `A`.  (2) So you’re saying that “Mary” is a special, hard-coded value? (3) Please post your sample data as text.

Comment: Its quit confusing, upload sample data.

Comment: `I need a formula that will:` Seems like you're demanding for us to write a script for you

Comment: I don't think a formula will work here though with VBA, it's surprisingly easy.

Comment: Actually,  doing it with a formula is ‘‘surprisingly easy’’.

Answer (score 1):

Put

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(E1 & "Mary", A$1:A$8 & B$1:B$8, 0)), VLOOKUP(E1, A$1:B$8, 2, 0), "Mary")
```

into cell `F1`
(adjusting the `8` to the number of rows of data that you have)
and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. 
Drag/fill down to `Fn` if desired.

The `MATCH` looks for a row where `An & Bn`
(`An` concatenated with `Bn`)
is `E1 & "Mary"` (`E1` concatenated with `"Mary"`). 
Such a row probably has `An` = `E1`
and `Bn` = `"Mary"`. 
If that returns an error, return `VLOOKUP(E1, A$1:B$8, 2, 0)` to `F1`. 
If it succeeds, we found a row with `"Mary"`, so return `"Mary"`.

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> makes the formula
an array formula.